# .removeClass() not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a productbutton and when clicked the button needs to be also visible in a sidepanel. You can click on multiple product buttons in the body which will be added to the list in this sidepanel.

Goal is to send an e-mail form with an overview of the selected products.

I need to sync the functionalities of these buttons. For example, when you deactivate a button the state needs to be updated as well in the sidepanel list as in the body.

I'm almost there, except that I cannot remove a class from the productbuttons in the body. (body_btn.removeClass('checked');)

I would be very glad glad if you can help me out!

```
$('.panel-toggle').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.slide-panel').toggleClass('opened');
});

// when question button is clicked switch the checked class
$('.question-trigger').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('checked')){

        $(this).removeClass('checked');
        $('.slide-panel .question-trigger').remove();

    } else {

        $(this).addClass('checked');
        $(this).clone().switchClass('body-btn', 'side-btn').appendTo('.slide-panel p');

    }


    $('.slide-panel .question-trigger').click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $(this).removeClass('checked');

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);

        var body_btn = $('.wpb_wrapper .question-trigger #'+id);
        console.log(body_btn);


        body_btn.removeClass('checked');

        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Also, are you sure `id` and `body_btn` are logged to the console?

Comment: Make sure all your `id` attributes are unique. I'm seeing `'.wpb_wrapper .question-trigger #'+id` and getting nervous. You never have to be specific with an `id` since there can be only one. Just use `$('#' + id)`.

Comment: @AndreFerraz The id and body_btn are logged to my console.